# Rcpp/C++: Fastest way to populate a matrix using the Armadillo library

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I have the following problem:
Suppose I have some input matrix X and I would like to compute a couple of summary statistics on its columns. Then I want to store the results for each column in a separate row of a new matrix. I'm using the armadillo library for all computations.

What is the best (fastest) way to do this without recomputing memory location each time accessing the output matrix? Here is an example using Rcpp:

```
cppFunction(depends="RcppArmadillo", code='         
 NumericMatrix foo(const arma::mat & X) {

   arma::mat out(X.n_cols, 4);

   for(int i = 0; i < X.n_cols; i++){
     out(i,0) = arma::min(X.col(i));
     out(i,1) = arma::max(X.col(i));
     out(i,2) = arma::mean(X.col(i));
     out(i,3) = arma::stddev(X.col(i));
   }

   return wrap(out);
   }
')

mat <- rnorm(100000)
dim(mat) <- c(100, 1000)
out <- foo(mat)
```

Thank's for your help!

Comment: Looks pretty reasonable.  Did you benchmark or profile it?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Hey, I haven't yet formally benchmarked it. What I tried is to to swap the indices of the output matrix and return its transpose at the end, but the transposition is too expensive. I hoped that there could be some fast solution using iterators on cols/rows.

Comment: @Dominik - or you can use the [running_stat_vec](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#running_stat_vec) class

Comment: @mtall I incidentially just tried this class (on another example) and found it to be slower than populating and then taking the mean, but maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: @Dominik - I don't think running_stat_vec is supposed to be faster than specialized code such as yours. The running_stat_vec class is meant to be convenient for calculating many statistics in one hit. Because it's calculating the stats without knowing the number of samples up front, it has to use alternative (and possibly slower) algorithms.